# Use variable inside regex rewrite test on nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I've got a network of Wordpress multisites running on nginx. I'm trying to set up caching using w3 total cache. I'm 99% there, but I'm just stuck on one rule.

I found [some instructions](http://elivz.com/blog/single/wordpress_with_w3tc_on_nginx/) that pointed me to this rewrite rule to rewrite minified css & js files with pretty URLS:

```
# Rewrite minified CSS and JS files
location ~* \.(css|js) {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/wp-content/w3tc/min/(.+\.(css|js))$ /wp-content/w3tc/min/index.php?file=$1 last;
    }
}
```

I modified it like so to work on my multisite environment:

```
rewrite ^/wp-content/w3tc-$host/min/(.+\.(css|js))$ /wp-content/w3tc-$host/min/index.php?file=$1 last;
```

However I found out that the test doesn't interpret the `$host` variable, instead it actually tests the string `"$host"`. Is there any way to actually use the value of the `$host` variable in the test? Alternatively, would it be a good idea to use a general rule, such as this:

```
rewrite ^/wp-content/w3tc-.*?/min/(.+\.(css|js))$ /wp-content/w3tc-$host/min/index.php?file=$1 last;
```

I'm open to better suggestions on this - regex is not a strong point for me.

And finally, for anyone searching for an alternative answer: it is possible to get minification working just by disabling *"Rewrite URL structure"* in the minification settings. This is purely for pretty URLs for the minified files.

Comment: Looking for some solution myself. As far as my research goes, variable interpolation is done by nginx on runtime whenever regular expressions are compiled on configuration time. So no joy. Looking for a workaround ...

Comment: If you do end up finding an answer, please let me know. I've given up so far, as it does work for me with ugly URLs. Which is good enough for CSS/JS files.

Comment: Gave up here too, doesn't seem to be implemented ever. Maybe a custom module someday, for now back to templating the configs.

Answer (score 1):

Variable interpolation isn't available in rewrite regexes.  I would use something like:

```
rewrite ^/wp-content/w3tc-(.*?)/min/(.+\.(css|js))$ /wp-content/w3tc-$1/min/index.php?file=$2 last;
```